# roll out of java web start clients

Tags: java, caching, proxy, java-web-start

We are about to roll out a client server application build with java web start. Our main server is located in a country in Europe and we will have many users downloading our client the first day from all over the world. Since the client application is quite big in MB our wan will be utilized a lot. Is there a way to cache or pre- distribute java web start clients to servers "closer" to the user (for example a local server)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Content Distribution Network such as akamai, edgecast or limelight. They do all the hard work for you.

Alternatively, spend the next few months buying servers at locations all around the world and making your own CDN, as that is what you are getting towards.

Comment: So there is nothing within java you can use? We already have other web start clients deployed. Just a thought.

Comment: Well if you already have servers deployed all over the world and you simply want to direct a user to the one closest, you could look at using GEOIP services to try to glean information about the user's location, then direct them to a particular server.

Comment: Why do you want to involve java? The .jnlp file simply states a url of the file to be downloaded. At the server-side of that url, you can do whatever load balancing you want (such as those described above).

Answer (score 0):

You can create an install CD. See [this](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/javaws/developersguide/cdinstall.03.06.html)